# Gráfico half-normal plot para modelos mistos ajustados com pacote nlme

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regressão

Estou tentando realizar o grafico half-normal plot para um modelo de efeitos mistos ajustado por meio da função `lme` do pacote `nlme`.

Abaixo encontra-se a rotina computacional, verificando-se o erro obtido.

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(hnp)

lmmNew3 <- lme(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                    (Var4)+(Var5),
                  random = list(Var6=pdDiag(~Var7)), Data, method="REML")

Grap1=hnp(lmmNew3, xlab = 'Theoretical quantiles', ylab = 'Residuals', 
          main = '')
G1 <- with(Grap1, data.frame(x, lower, upper, median, residuals))
ggplot(data = G1, aes(x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = residuals)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = lower)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = upper)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = median), linetype = "dashed") + 
  ylab("Residuals") +
  xlab("Theoretical quantiles") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 17),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 17),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20,color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20,color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 25))

Error in hnp.default(lmmNew3, xlab = "Theoretical quantiles", ylab = "Residuals",  : 
  This function has not been implemented for objects of class 'lme'. If you wish to supply your own fitting, simulation and diagnostic extration codes,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternativas para o seu problema:

1. Você precisa programar uma função para o `nlme::lme` funcionar com o pacote `hnp`. É isso o que o erro está sugerindo.

Eu nunca trabalhei em cima dessa possibilidade, mas o autor do pacote explica como fazer no `?hnp`:

> "Users can also use a numeric vector as `object`and `hnp` will
> generate the (half-)normal plot with asimulated envelope using the
> standard normal distribution `(scale=F)` or
> `N(\mu,\sigma^2)(scale=T)`. Implementing a new model class is done by
> providing three functions to `hnp:diagfun` - to obtain model
> diagnostics, `simfun`- to simulate random variables and `fitfun`- to
> refit the model to simulated variables. The way these functions must
> be written is shown in the Examples section."

Eu também gosto de ajustar o `LMM` via `lme`, só que é uma implementação mais antiga e talvez por isso o pessoal tem usado menos (porém é mais estável que a `lmer`), .

Dessa forma, eu passei a visualizar esses diagnósticos ajustando via `lmer` opção 2:

2. Pegar esse mesmo modelo e estimar via `lme4::lmer` e executar `hnp::hnp()` no resultado do modelo através desse pacote.

```
Data <- read.csv2("Data.csv")
library(lme4)
lmmNew3 <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                     (Var4)+(Var5) + (Var7||Var6),
                   Data, REML=T)
hnp::hnp(lmmNew3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas como por último lançaram o pacote `glmmTMB` que é mais rápido que os dois últimos, eu prefiro usar 3ª opção, que é avaliar os resíduos através  do pacote `DHARMa`, que acomoda objetos `glmmTMB` (O `hnp` não acomoda objetos `glmmTMB`).

3. Pegar esse mesmo modelo e realizar os diagnósticos de resíduos através do pacote [DHARMa](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html). Mas eles também não fornecem suporte para o `nlme::lme`. Dessa forma você também precisa ter o modelo da forma `lme4::lmer`, ou ainda, `glmmTMB::glmmTMB`.

```
library(glmmTMB)
lmmNew3 <- glmmTMB(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                     (Var4)+(Var5) + (Var7||Var6),
                   Data, REML=T)
library(DHARMa)
simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = lmmNew3, plot = F)
plot(simulationOutput)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em ambos diagnósticos, é possível ver que o ajuste não está satisfatório em termos dos resíduos.

Comment: O que significa `random = list(Var6=pdDiag(~Var7))`?
É efeito aleatório de intercepto para a variável `Var7`?